# dropdown list pais y cuidad

Tags: postgresql, jsf, primefaces, jpa

nesecito ayuda con un problema que tengo, lo que pasa es que nesecito 2 dropdown,los cuales uno es de paises y el otro es de cuidades, ya tengo el de paises, pero me falta el de cuidades,el cual solo debe traer las cuidades de ese pais.

```js
este el BusinessWeb
    public List<SelectItem> getAllDepartamentos() throws Exception {
        try {
            List<SelectItem> resultSelectItems = new ArrayList();
            List<DepartamentoDTO> allDepartamentos = new ArrayList(usuarioFacade.getallDepartamentos());
            resultSelectItems.add(new SelectItem(null, "Seleccione un departamento.."));
            for (int i = 0; i < allDepartamentos.size(); i++) {
                resultSelectItems.add(new SelectItem(allDepartamentos.get(i).getNombreDepartamento()));
            }
            return resultSelectItems;
        } catch (BusinessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BusinessWeb.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return new ArrayList();
        }
    }
```

```html
y este es el xhtml
                    <p:outputLabel for="departamento" value="Departamento"/>  
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="departamento"  
                                     style="width:170px" 
                                     required="false" 
                                     requiredMessage="seleccione uno"
                                     filter="true"
                                     filterMatchMode="startsWith"
                                     panelStyle="width:200px"
                                     value="#{usuarioBean.ipsDTO.ipsDepartamento}"> 
                        <f:selectItems value="#{usuarioBean.allDepartamentos}"/>     
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                    <p:outputLabel for="cuidad" value="Cuidad" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="cuidad"  
                                     style="width:160px" 
                                     required="false" 
                                     requiredMessage="seleccione una Cuidad"  
                                     filter="true"  
                                     filterMatchMode="startsWith"
                                    panelStyle="width:200px">                     
                        <f:selectItems values"" />                        
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

se que una forma es filtrar por id, ya que  ambos datos, estan relacionados en una base de datos, cada uno con su tabla,las cuales tiene un respectiva fk, el problema es que no se como implementar eso al proyecto.

Comment: ¿Tu duda es como implementar el modelo de base de datos? ¿O como hacer con jsf que el dropdown de ciudades se actualice según la opción elegida en el dropdown de departamentos?

Comment: si exacto hacer que se el jsf se actualize dependiendo a lo seleccionado

Answer (score 0):

Hay un ejemplo en el showcase de primefaces. Te dejo el [link](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/dropdown.xhtml).

Basicamente lo que hace el ejemplo es usar un método en el bean que se ejecutará por ajax cada vez que se seleccione un país, y al volver la respuesta al browser, se actualiza la porción de html referida a las ciudades (update="city")

En el xhtml

```
<p:ajax listener="#{dropdownView.onCountryChange}" update="city" />
```

Y en la clase java

```
public void onCountryChange() {
    if(country !=null && !country.equals(""))
        cities = data.get(country);
    else
        cities = new HashMap<String, String>();
}
```

Deberías poder adaptar tu código para hacer algo parecido a esto. Cada vez que elijas un país, deberías ir a buscar las ciudades y actualizar tu lista.